# How to solve TSS.MSR CPP build error in linux

Tags: c++, linux, tpm, tss

trying to run the makefile in TSS.CPP directory (downloaded from https://github.com/microsoft/ms-tpm-20-ref/tree/main) gives me openssl/sm3.h error file not found

I already tried
`sudo apt install libssl-dev`
the error is still there

do i need to do something else? before running the makefile? I run this on Ubuntu

Comment: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commits/master/include/internal/sm3.h looks like this header is not supposed to be used directly in the client code

Comment: @pptaszni which one is the client code? is the src files in TSS.CPP directory considered the client code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's written here https://github.com/microsoft/ms-tpm-20-ref/issues/50  `sm3.h` shouldn't be used directly. So, it's issue of code developers. Of cause you could copy the headers to `/usr/include/openssl` and may be your build would be succeed.

PS `sm3.h` places in `<openssl_source>/include/internals/`. You could obtain sources by the command `apt source openssl`

Comment: okay it actually works, i just commented out the line that requires sm3.h. but is this safe? like it fixed my build right now but would it be okay for production?

Comment: Yes, it's safe. `sm3_` functions and types never used anywhere in the code of MsTpm. Also you could fix inequality, i.e. replace `OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x10101010L` to `OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x10200000L`

Comment: Thank you very much. your response is a huge help~